# Laravel & Docker - The stream or file \"/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log\" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, laravel-8

I am new to Docker world. I am trying to start a laravel project in Docker but when I run `docker-compose up nginx` I get this error message.

```
The stream or file \"/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log\" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx.dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - php

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
      MYSQL_USER: laravel
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html

  composer:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: composer.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
```

This is my php.dockerfile

```
FROM php:8-fpm-alpine

ENV PHPGROUP=laravel
ENV PHPUSER=laravel

RUN adduser -g ${PHPGROUP} -s /bin/sh -D ${PHPUSER}

RUN sed -i "s/user = www-data/user = ${PHPUSER}/g" /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
RUN sed -i "s/group = www-data/group = ${PHPGROUP}/g" /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/public

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql


CMD ["php-fpm", "-y", "/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf", "-R"]
```

I've searched the internet for a solution and executed some commands but I still get the same problem.
Any idea what's going wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: you are mounting the storage directly from host to container, if they are in different user, then you are getting into permission issue (which your container seems running as www-data), `chmod -R 777 ./src/storage` will do the tricks but please do more research on linux permission before you do this

Comment: **COPY** the `./src` folder to `/var/www/html` at built time. Add the `copy` line to your `dockerfile` and add `RUN chown -R www-data /var/www/html`

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution for this problem for the past two days, ended up finding it on a excruciating 15 minute YouTube video that unbelievably actually got it right.

1. SSH into the container with `sail shell` or use the Docker container
   terminal directly from its dashboard;
2. Run `chown -R sail:sail storage`;
3. Problem solved.

This is because the user `sail` has the same `UID` of `1000` as your actual Linux user, which owns the directory `storage` in your host machine.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
chown -R sail:sail storage
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Permission Denied Error Laravel + Docker Setup]

Permission Denied Error--------
SSH into the container with `sail shell` or use the Docker container terminal directly from its dashboard;
Run `chown -R sail:sail .;`
Problem solved.
#note I used  https://stackoverflow.com/a/74881275/18835623 answer to solve my permission problem so credit goes to him :D
my device :
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) x86_64
Host: Aspire E5-576 V1.49
Kernel: 6.1.0-11-amd64
Shell: bash 5.2.15
DE: Xfce 4.18
CPU: Intel i3-8130U (4) @ 3.400GHz
GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 620
Memory: 8909MiB / 11838MiB

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was the following

I logged in inside the container and I removed the existing laravel.log file

```
docker exec -it 0a6ea1039145 bash

root@0a6ea1039145:/var/www/html/storage/logs# ls -la
-rwxrwxrwx 1 1000 sail    14 Apr  2 21:21 .gitignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 sail 41664 Apr  3 20:41 laravel.log

root@0a6ea1039145:/var/www/html/storage/logs# rm laravel.log
```